# Working with .NET classes in Delphi by using mscorlib

Tags: delphi, pascal, mscorlib

I would like to use .NET classes in Delphi. I included mscorlib unit (which is a TLB) and want to create an instance of e.g. Assembly class. So I have:

```
uses mscorlib;

var myAssembly: _Assembly;

begin
  myAssembly:=CoAssembly.Create;
  ...
end.
```

The application is compiled successfully, but when starting it I get an error message saying that the class is not registered.

Any idea how this can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

By using mscorlib for delphi to call c#.

You can take a look at `JEDI` or `DDNRuntime`.

`TJclClrHost` in JEDI.

`DDNRuntime` is wrapper for delphi to call c#.

#### Features

- No need for COM support.
- It is very simple to use, just declare the type and method of .NET in Delphi.
- Dedicated translation tool, input one or more .NET assembly DLL, output one or two Delphi import units.
- Support interface types.
- Support dynamic array (one-dimensional array).
- Support Delegate type.
- Support Event.
- Generic type (Limited support. Only XE8 and above are supported and nested generics are not supported yet, such as: `DNICollection<DNKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` such multi-level nesting).

https://github.com/ying32/DDNRuntime-examples